# C#: Select statement does not appear the right result

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I created function analyze students result table. The aim is : Find the highest average result which grouped by Content type. For Example:

```
S_Id      ContentType      Result
1              T             50
1              V             70
1              G             30
1              G             40
1              V             60
```

The output that i need it is V because the average of V is the highest.

This is my Code but it does not display the right result:
My output display the fifth row in the table.

```
public string analyzeResultTable(string studentId)
{
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AHSConnection"].ToString();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataSet dsAns = new DataSet();
    string BestPrefrence = "";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd2 =
            new MySqlCommand(
                "Select ContentType, MAX(avgContent) from (select ContentType, AVG(result) as avgContent from dopractice where S_Id='" +
                    studentId + "' GROUP BY ContentType) AS T", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
    }

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        BestPrefrence = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
    }
    return BestPrefrence;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear that this has *anything* to do with C# (although you should learn to use parameterized SQL). Have you tried making this query directly in MySQL?

Comment: I do not have a good experience in writing MySql statements in C#

Comment: But the problem isn't with the C# - it's with the SQL. Get your query working in a MySQL tool first, then move it to C#... and when you do, use parameterized SQL. (If you don't know how to do that, just search for "parameterized sql mysql c#" and you'll find lots of results.

Comment: The average of your values is 52. None of which the values in the table match. Which row are you expecting to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this wil give you the average result for each ContentType

```
select ContentType, AVG(result) as avgContent from dopractice where S_Id='" + studentId + "' GROUP BY ContentType order by AVG(result) desc limit 1;
```

after adding order by you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is not correct. It can be something like below.

**Code**

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("select ContentType, AVG(Result) as AvgContent 
                         from dopractice 
                         where S_Id='" + studentId + "' 
                         group by ContentType order by 2 desc limit 1;", conn);
```

And I strongly recommend you to use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection.

**Code**

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("select ContentType, AVG(Result) as AvgContent 
                         from dopractice 
                         where S_Id= @S_Id
                         group by ContentType order by 2 desc limit 1;", conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Id", studentId);
```